ASP.NET MVC - RDLC File not being located when the project is published and hosted locally
I have this solution in VS 2022 that has 3 projects:

ASP.NET MVC web app (which is the main project)
Class library (for generating the RDLC report, I had to do this because creating an RDLC report inside the web app project doesn't let me choose the type of data sources: Object, Database, and Service)
Another class library (since I am using object as my data source, I had to create this to handle the classes or what I call entities)

In my 2nd class library, I have this code block
Now the string reportPath, as you can see, goes up one directory.
However, when I published this app and hosted it locally using IIS manager, it errors because the path of the LOI - MMP.rdlc files has been changed to:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CashtreaSubsystem\bin\Reports

The commented line in the screenshot above also doesn't work, because what it does is fetch the directory of where this method is being executed (which is in the web app project).
What I tried is the commented line in the screenshot above.

Can't you just add a ReportPath config setting and set that as needed?

I never thought of that idea. I might as well try that now. Thanks @marc_s
